# change timer of an event (libevent)

Tags: c++, c, libevent

Is it correct to free an event and then set a new time on it?
For example:

```
void cb(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void * arg)
{
   ...
   event_free(event);
   set_time(300);
   ...
}
void set_timer(unsigned int seconds)
{
   ...
   event = event_new( base, -1, EV_TIMEOUT | EV_PERSIST, cb, args );
   if ( event ) {
      struct timeval tv = { seconds, 0 };
      event_add( event, &tv );
    }
   ...
}
```

I would like to use only one event for this change, not more. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a good reason you are freeing and recreating the event instead of simply reusing it?

Comment: Do you mean event_free is not needed?

Comment: The [documentation](https://libevent.org/doc/event_8h.html#ab0c85ebe9cf057be1aa17724c701b0c8) requires that `event_new` or `event_assign` must have been called previously, but otherwise it "replaces the old timeout with the new one if tv is non-NULL."